# Calculating the product of sequential items in a list with varying interval lenghts

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have been trying to calculate the product of sequential items in a dataframe or list based on intervals of different lenghts. In essence, I would like to calculate nQx from a list of Qx values given an irregular interval size.

```
dComp <- data.frame(AGE = seq(0,74), MORTALITY=c(869,58,40,37,36,35,32,28,29,23,24,22,24,28,
33,52,57,77,93,103,103,109,105,114,108,112,119,125,117,127,125,134,134,131,152,179,173,
182,199,203,232,245,296,315,335,356,405,438,445,535,594,623,693,749,816,915,994,1128,1172,
1294,1473,1544,1721,1967,2129,2331,2559,2901,3203,3470,3782,4348,4714,5245,5646)/100000)  

x <- c(0,1,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70) 
n <- c(diff(x),999) 
n
[1]   1   4   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5 999
```

For 1 item I am able to find the value:

First caluculate Px:

```
Px <- sapply(dComp$MORTALITY, function(Qx) (1 - Qx))
```

For  the interval from x = [1,4]

```
1- prod(Px[2:5])
```

How do you implement this over the entire interval list. In vba I would use a for loop but I understood that in R the apply procedures are used. PS: Can anybody suggest a good R instruction book?

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you're trying to do. Could you please clarify things a bit more? What's item 1? Why do you multiply the values Px[2:5] and subtract it with 1? etc..

Comment: Seems like it was just me. Ignore my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine `tapply` and `cut`:

```
## no need for sapply in your Px calculation
Px <- 1 - dComp$MORTALITY

## definie intervals
breaks <- c(0,1,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70, 999) 

## using tapply to run the function for each interval (use cut for grouping by AGE)
tapply(X=Px, INDEX=cut(dComp$AGE, breaks=breaks, right=FALSE), FUN=function(x)1-prod(x))
```

Output:

```
      [0,1)       [1,5)      [5,10)     [10,15)     [15,20)     [20,25)     [25,30)     [30,35)     [35,40)     [40,45)     [45,50)     [50,55)     [55,60)     [60,65) 
0.008690000 0.001708920 0.001469140 0.001309318 0.003814265 0.005378395 0.005985625 0.006741766 0.009325056 0.014149626 0.021601755 0.034271934 0.053836246 0.085287751 
    [65,70)    [70,999) 
0.136549522 0.215953304
```

Comment: Tks sgibb,  but cuts are not correct yet. Age x=0 is the first interval. Next interval is [1,4], [5,9] etc

Comment: @Arrose: I use left closed intervals, now.